# select2 placeholder not clearing after setting values

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a multi-value select2 field that I'm populating with some values returned from a server. However, after I've set these values in the select2, my placeholder is still showing.

I've tried setting `$("#my-select").data("select2").opts.placeholder` to null, but corresponding calls to setPlaceholder() have generated errors. I've tried setting the values using `$("#my-select").select2("val", myDefaultData)`, but that didn't pre-populate the select2 field.

Here is the code that's initializing the select2 field:

```
$("#my-select").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "/my/rest/endpoint",
        dataType: "json",
        delay: 250, 
        data: function(params) {

            return {
                name: params
            };

        },
        method: "get",
        results: function(data, page) {

            return {
                results: data
            };

        },
        cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    placeholder: "Select...",
    multiple: true
});
```

Here's the block that's populating the `$("#my-select")` field with data returned from the server:

```
$("#my-select").data().select2.updateSelection(defaults["my-select-values"]);
$("#my-select").change();
```

What happens after those 2 lines run is that my select2 field has the values from defaults, followed by "Select...". The placeholder finally clears when I click the field, but I want the "Select..." to disappear upon the values being put into the select2 field. How can I adjust my updateSelection() call to remove the placeholder text in addition to setting the values?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution is to populate the data using:

```
$("#my-select").select2("data", defaults["my-select-values"]);
```